# git p4 submit -- fails on 'could not determine file type'?

Tags: macos, git, perforce, p4v, git-p4

Periodically, when I'm doing `git p4 submit`, I get a nasty error:

```
Could not determine file type for rails_project/public/favicon.ico 
(result: '//mydepot/main/rails_project/public/favicon.ico#1 - add 
default change (binary+l) *exclusive*')
```

In each case, it's some odd binary-type file that confuses the thing (like the favicon.ico above), or (most often) a graphic, like a PNG. And this kills the submit and leaves all the files that were opened before it in an opened state, but not yet submitted...

Resolving this ends up being a pain in the ass, where I end up having to use p4v to go in and manually submit half of what I was trying to submit via a new changelist, and then finish my submit (crossing my fingers that I don't hit another weird file and get stuck again).

*(this is on git version 1.8.3.2 on a Mac with OS X Mountain Lion)*

**Has anyone come up with a way to make `git p4` behave properly? Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/ermshiperete/git-p4/blob/master/git-p4 for "Could not determine file type for " the regex '`re.match(".*\((.+)\)\r?$", result)`' isn't matching against '`//mydepot/main/rails_project/public/favicon.ico#1 - add 
default change (binary+l) *exclusive*`'.

I guess "`*exclusive*`" is new from perforce. or at least the git-p4 developer(s) haven't encountered it.

The easiest solution is probably to teach git-p4 about the new perforce syntax, and submit a patch.

EDIT:

Thinking about it - you probably don't want to use git-p4 for any files you (or your company) have decided should have exclusive locks, since git will break the exclusiveness of the locks.